# finding the worst-case runtime using O-notation

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, runtime, big-o, computer-science

I am new to O-notation and am trying to determine the tightest bound of worst case run time using big-O notation from these given bounds:

1. O(1)
2. O(log n)
3. O(n)
4. O(n log n)
5. O(n**2)
6. O(n**3)
7. O(2**n)
   As practice, I am adding the tightest bound in a comment for all my codes but I couldn't figure out which of the cases would be used with abstract list functions. As an example, I have two simple codes below to find the sums:

examples:

```
def sums1(L):
  even = list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, L))
  odd = list(filter(lambda x: x%2==1, L))
  return even + odd

def susm2(L):
  if L == []: 
    return 0
  s1 = sum(L)
  s2 = sums2(L[1:])
  s3 = sums2(L[2:])
  return s1+s2+s3
```

From my understanding the first code would run O(n^2) times because two abstract lists are being added and the second would run O(2^n). However, I couldn't find any similar codes online to see if I was correct about this so I thought I'd ask here. Any guidance on how many times either will run is greatly appreciated. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `sums1`, I believe you will have a complexity of O(n), where `n` is the number of elements in `L`. To elaborate:

```
def sums1(L):
    even = list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, L)) # O(n)
    odd = list(filter(lambda x: x%2==1, L))  # O(n)
    return even + odd                        # O(n)
```

Creating the `odd` and `even` lists takes O(n) for each, as you need to traverse L twice.

Concatenating the two lists, `odd` and `even` in also linear, O(n). Because to concatenate two lists, on the worst case you have to traverse the first, until you find its last element.